# Two way delegation?

Tags: protocols, x.509

I am looking into using the X.509 for mutual delegation where mutual delegation is bi-directional where an entity can only delegate a task or a set of permissions to another entity if the latter is also permitted to delegate back a different task or set of permissions to the first entity

the above is a theoretical secarino where i am trying to create a protocol to solve

this protocol is entirely theoretical but i would like to make it as real world as possible

it is for a school project

i have drawn a rough sketch of what i think is a possible solution, would a protocol like the one below work ? if not what issues would it have ?

Thanks

[image]

Also if the above example is ok, what message would A have to send to the server to state it has roles to delegate to B etc

Anyone ?

Comment: The SSL/TLS protocol allows for mutual authentication.  An application using this protocol could delegate tasks using the x509 cert as an identity.

Comment: Hi there, could you please elaborate on your comment, as it sounds like what i am trying to achieve thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [establish an SSL/TLS connection with mutual authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34897/configure-ssl-mutual-two-way-authentication).  In an x509 client certificate the `Common Name` could be a username for access control.

Comment: Thanks, i have authentication first via SSL to achieve mutual authentication, how would this be then used to check both can delegate tasks and then sign the x509 certif

Comment: @user2061913 you need a PKI for that.  OpenPKI is an example.